# Homestead with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, frameworks, homestead

I've setup Homstead which is working fine, but the web site is showing 403 forbidden error.  If I put a index.php file in the public folder then it shows the content of the index.php file as expected. I have removed the index.php file and setup a laravel app within the public folder. This creates the 403 forbidden error again. If I point the web browser to homestead.app/lts/resources/views/welcome.blade.php it will show the laravel welcome page. 'lts' is the name of the project, it looks like laravel is not loading or pointing to the correct file to load. Any help will be much appreciated. I am new to laravel, I use to use codeigniter so I do understand how frameworks, work a little.

Comment: Post nginx log file contents

Comment: You need to start over. "Setting up in the public folder" is incorrect, the public folder and index.php is part of Laravel. Laravel is installed in the root and includes the public folder and an index.php.

Comment: Thanks Niklas everything is pointing to the web browser as it should after your advice. I followed a tutorial how to get Homestead running but it never show you where lararvel should go in relation to the public folder.         Thanks again.